# Trying to install AngularJS, but I can't install Yeoman

Tags: 14.04, nodejs, npm

I'm trying to install AngularJS though Yeoman, but I keep running into problems and can't install Yeoman. My version of NodeJS is v0.12.10 (updated, as far as I can tell), my npm verison is 3.7.3 (also updated, I believe).

Here's what happens when I try to install Yeoman:

```
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
/home/marieficid/.node/bin/yo -> /home/marieficid/.node/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js

> yo@1.6.0 postinstall /home/marieficid/.node/lib/node_modules/yo
> yodoctor


Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
✖ Node.js version

Your Node.js version is outdated.
Upgrade to the latest version: https://nodejs.org

✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✖ npm version

Your npm version is outdated.

Upgrade to the latest version by running:
npm install -g npm


Found potential issues on your machine :(
yo@1.6.0 /home/marieficid/.node/lib/node_modules/yo
├── titleize@1.0.0
├── figures@1.4.0
├── user-home@2.0.0 (os-homedir@1.0.1)
├── opn@3.0.3 (object-assign@4.0.1)
├── humanize-string@1.0.1 (decamelize@1.1.2)
├── string-length@1.0.1 (strip-ansi@3.0.1)
├── async@1.5.2
├── repeating@2.0.0 (is-finite@1.0.1)
├── root-check@1.0.0 (downgrade-root@1.1.0, sudo-block@1.2.0)
├── sort-on@1.2.2 (arrify@1.0.1, dot-prop@2.3.0)
├── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, supports-color@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1, has-ansi@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2.2.0)
├── yeoman-character@1.1.0 (supports-color@3.1.2)
├── yosay@1.1.0 (strip-ansi@3.0.1, ansi-regex@2.0.0, word-wrap@1.1.0, pad-component@0.0.1, minimist@1.2.0, taketalk@1.0.0, ansi-styles@2.2.0, string-width@1.0.1)
├── configstore@1.4.0 (os-tmpdir@1.0.1, object-assign@4.0.1, graceful-fs@4.1.3, xdg-basedir@2.0.0, uuid@2.0.1, osenv@0.1.3, write-file-atomic@1.1.4, mkdirp@0.5.1)
├── update-notifier@0.6.0 (is-npm@1.0.0, latest-version@2.0.0, semver-diff@2.1.0)
├── package-json@2.3.1 (registry-url@3.0.3, semver@5.1.0, rc@1.1.6)
├── npm-keyword@4.2.0 (object-assign@4.0.1, pinkie-promise@2.0.0, registry-url@3.0.3)
├── cross-spawn-async@2.1.9 (lru-cache@4.0.0, which@1.2.4)
├── got@5.4.1 (lowercase-keys@1.0.0, is-stream@1.0.1, timed-out@2.0.0, is-redirect@1.0.0, is-plain-obj@1.1.0, is-retry-allowed@1.0.0, unzip-response@1.0.0, object-assign@4.0.1, node-status-codes@1.0.0, read-all-stream@3.1.0, duplexer2@0.1.4, pinkie-promise@2.0.0, create-error-class@2.0.1, url-parse-lax@1.0.0, readable-stream@2.0.5, parse-json@2.2.0)
├── fullname@2.1.0 (pify@2.3.0, pinkie-promise@2.0.0, npmconf@2.1.2)
├── inquirer@0.11.4 (strip-ansi@3.0.1, ansi-regex@2.0.0, ansi-escapes@1.1.1, through@2.3.8, cli-width@1.1.1, string-width@1.0.1, readline2@1.0.1, run-async@0.1.0, cli-cursor@1.0.2, rx-lite@3.1.2)
├── meow@3.7.0 (trim-newlines@1.0.0, map-obj@1.0.1, object-assign@4.0.1, decamelize@1.1.2, minimist@1.2.0, camelcase-keys@2.0.0, redent@1.0.0, loud-rejection@1.3.0, normalize-package-data@2.3.5)
├── read-pkg-up@1.0.1 (find-up@1.1.0, read-pkg@1.1.0)
├── yeoman-environment@1.5.2 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, log-symbols@1.0.2, grouped-queue@0.3.2, text-table@0.2.0, untildify@2.1.0, debug@2.2.0, diff@2.2.1, mem-fs@1.1.2, globby@4.0.0)
├── lodash@3.10.1
├── insight@0.7.0 (object-assign@4.0.1, lodash.debounce@3.1.1, tough-cookie@2.2.1, os-name@1.0.3, inquirer@0.10.1, request@2.69.0)
└── yeoman-doctor@2.1.0 (object-values@1.0.0, log-symbols@1.0.2, semver@5.1.0, each-async@1.1.1, bin-version-check@2.1.0, twig@0.8.8)
```

When I try to run `sudo npm install -g npm`:

```
marieficid@mariana-K46CB:~/Documentos/AngularTutorial$ sudo npm install -g npm
/home/marieficid/.node/bin/npm -> /home/marieficid/.node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@3.7.3 /home/marieficid/.node/lib/node_modules/npm
```

And here's what happens when I try to update nodejs:

```
marieficid@mariana-K46CB:~/Documentos/AngularTutorial$ sudo npm install -g n
/home/marieficid/.node/bin/n -> /home/marieficid/.node/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
n@2.1.0 /home/marieficid/.node/lib/node_modules/n
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.